# before domnodeinserted - javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-events

is it possible to launch an event before the node is inserted? I know that "domnodeinserted" works in gecko based browsers but I that code is executed after the node is inserted. I actually want to execute a code before the node is inserted. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there is but the real question is: why do you need this? The DOM is only a view model, any logic should be handled by your underlying JavaScript model.

Comment: I'm more-or-less in agreement with @Frits. There's really no need for a `domnodeinserted` or a `beforedomnodeinserted` event. Assuming you can modify the JS that runs on the page, you can write equivalent code without any sort of event handling.

Comment: I have to detect the paste events and if there is html inside I have to configure it, that's why I actually need it before the node is inserted :)

Comment: Then isn't some combination of `beforepaste` and `paste` events what you really want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such event. There is nothing in the [list of DOM mutation events specified by DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) (or even [DOM Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents)) that does what you want.